# Intersection of a chain of closed sets

Tags: general-topology, well-orders

I was recently attempting proving a conjecture of mine about the existence of certain minimal nonempty closed sets in a topological space. I opted to use Zorn's Lemma, and the proof would go through except for the following problem:

**Question:**
In a topological space $X$, let $\mathcal{A} = \{A_\lambda : \lambda\in\Lambda\} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ be a chain of nonempty closed sets, under $\subseteq$. When is $A = \bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda} A_\lambda$ nonempty?

**One possible avenue:** This question appears similar to the [Cantor Intersection Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem) and its variants. However, that theorem requires the chain to be countable, and it also requires some additional conditions on the members of the chain. Can we get a general version when $\Lambda$ is uncountable? Perhaps there is a way involving a well-ordering on $\Lambda$?

Comment: It is well-known, that a space is compact, if and only if every chain of non-empty closed subsets has non-empty intersection. For T2 spaces this is, for instance, Engelking, General Topology, Exercise 3.12.1. For the "$\Rightarrow$" part see also the answer of  Moishe Kohan below. The "$\Leftarrow$" part is more complicated, but can also be proven without T2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof of Cantor's theorem presented in Wikipedia is suboptimal (anybody can edit a Wikipedia article, no matter how little do they know about the subject). Here is a more general proof that answers (I hope) your question which is a bit open-ended.

Theorem. Suppose that $K$ is a compact topological space and $\{A_j: j\in J\}$ is a chain of nonempty closed subsets of $K$ (ordered with respect to the inclusion. Then the intersection
$$
\bigcap_{j\in J} A_j
$$
is nonempty.

Proof. It is useful to rewrite the definition of compactness using closed subsets:

A topological space $X$ is compact if and only if for every family $\{C_i: i\in I\}$ of closed subsets of $X$ with empty intersection, there exists a finite (nonempty) subset $F\subset I$ such that
$$
\bigcap_{i\in F} C_i=\emptyset. 
$$

Now, back to the proof of the theorem. Suppose, for the sake of a contradiction, that
$$
\bigcap_{j\in J} A_j=\emptyset. 
$$
Then, by compactness of $K$, there exists a finite subset $F\subset J$ such that
$$
\bigcap_{j\in F} A_j=\emptyset. 
$$
Let $A_i$ be the smallest among $A_j, j\in F$. Then
$$
A_i=\bigcap_{j\in F} A_j=\emptyset. 
$$
A contradiction (since we assumed that each $A_j$ is nonempty). qed

Comment: Makes sense to me! This is certainly much clearer than what's on Wikipedia for Cantor's theorem.